# Custom behaviour of RelatedField while Serialization

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I have two model below with foreign key relation.

```
class City(TimeStampedModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    long_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Address(TimeStampedModel):
         address_object = GenericForeignKey('address_content_type', 'object_id')
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='address_city')
```

And I have defined Below serializer for Address

```
class CityRelation(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, City):
            return CitySerializer(value).data

class AddressBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = CityRelation(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('id', 'uuid', 'address1', 'address2', 'landmark', 'city')
    @atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        address_book = Address(**validated_data)
        address_book.save()
        return address_book

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.address1 = validated_data['address1']
        instance.address2 = validated_data['address2']
        instance.landmark = validated_data['landmark']
        instance.city = validated_data['city']
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Here While Deserializing i want to pass only city_id in JSON but while serializing i want complete city object....so i override relatedfield...but i am getting error in deserialization. I also tried to override `to_internal_value()` method but it did not called during deserialization. How can i do that??

Comment: Try PrimaryKeyRelatedField. What's the error?

Comment: @CarltonGibson "to_internal_value()" method not get called...i debug above code and its not going there..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it...Actually i set `readonly=True` for city relation but with readonly only `to_representation()` get called not `to_internal_value()`...so i passed queryset...